Proper way to have a name
I recently changed my name to Karim and was told that it is not proper so do I use Abdul Karim or Abdur Karim and does adding a hyphen between the two names make a difference.

Karim is not improper, but anyway, Abdul Karim (Abdu AlKarim -> Abdu-lKarim -> Abdul-Karim) is correct and not Abdur Karim which has no meaning as far as I can say ...
